# Why am I unable to respawn in the campaign?

Tags: xbox-360, gears-of-war-3

This doesn't happen 100% of the time but when I play arcade campaign with my other half and one of us dies, the count down to respawn stops at 0:01 and doesn't allow the player to respawn. I cannot take part in the rest of the chapter. When in this state and the other players transition to the next chapter, I am then standing out of the game world and the only option is to reload the game.

Any ideas how to make this stop? I've looked through the official forums and couldn't find anything that helped. I thought it was to do with the fact I had the game installed on my Xbox but I have deleted it and its still happening.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try clearing the cache, uninstalling the game and re-installing. Maybe just playing from the disc if that fails. Re-downloading any patches. Basic stuff - sometimes things can get screwy. Aside from that, it may be a glitch so be sure to report it on the forums so it can get fixed.

Comment: I've already uninstalled the game and have been playing off of the disk. If it keeps happening then I will report it.

Comment: Yah, it's always important to try to the basic trouble-shooting, just in case.